# What was Silva talking about when he reached the chapel in Skyfall?

Tags: plot-explanation, james-bond, skyfall

In the last scenes of [Skyfall](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1074638/) when Silva finds M in the chapel, he looks around and speaks

> Of course! it had to be here. It had to be this way.

What was he talking about? Was he referring to something that only he and M knew?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's not about something that only he and M knew , it's about the place and the situation that they were in.**

Silva hated the whole institution of MI6 of which M was the Head. His [hatred for M](https://jamesbond.fandom.com/wiki/Raoul_Silva) was much more as M was a mother-like figure to him. Later he was sacrificed by his organisation for the exchange of six prisoners in China and he held M to be responsible for that.

To Silva, that(mother abandoning her child) was a sin. M giving order to the agents to kill people are also sins.

> .....and sending her a message advising her to "think on her sins"
>   before bombing her office ...
>
> [<sub>*Source*</sub>](https://jamesbond.fandom.com/wiki/Raoul_Silva)

So, when they meet each other for one final time, Silva sees it is in a chapel. He knows that, he (the child) has and still is going to commit a sin(killing M) and M has also done many. He thinks it couldn't be better than a chapel where the one who had committed sins will get justice and mercy both. Hence he says,

> Of course! it had to be here. It had to be this way.